# SQL: How to calculate percentage increase using partition by with multiple columns

Tags: sql, hive, cloudera, impala, hue

I have 6 columns named as TOTAL_STOCK_VALUE,VALUE_UNRESTRICTED,fiscal_year,fiscal_period,plant,storage_location.I want to create a new column with percentage increase value from column TOTAL_STOCK_VALUE,VALUE_UNRESTRICTED.

```
Sample data : 
TOTAL_STOCK_VALUE  VALUE_UNRESTRICTED  fiscal_year  fiscal_period  plant  storage_location
336.0                228.0                 2019         10          ABC         AR40
418.0                209.0                 2019         10          ABC         IN80
162.0                0.000                 2020         04          CTF         KK29
86412.0              53060.0               2020         04          ARZ         HD91
```

```
Desired Output :
TOTAL_STOCK_VALUE  VALUE_UNRESTRICTED  fiscal_year  fiscal_period  plant  storage_location  New
336.0                228.0                 2019         10          ABC         AR40       32.14%
418.0                209.0                 2019         10          ABC         IN80        50%
162.0                0.000                 2020         04          CTF         KK29        100%
86412.0              53060.0               2020         04          ARZ         HD91       38.59%
```

used query :

```
select
    TOTAL_STOCK_VALUE,
    VALUE_UNRESTRICTED,
    fiscal_year,
    fiscal_period,
    plant,
    storage_location,
    ((TOTAL_STOCK_VALUE - VALUE_UNRESTRICTED) / TOTAL_STOCK_VALUE) * 100 over(partition by fiscal_year,fiscal_period,plant,storage_location) as New
from
    MyTable
```

The above query is not giving the desired result and throws an error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: I dont see any aggregate function or `order by` in your sql. Possible to add and try?

Comment: @KoushikRoy No, I only want to perform that simple math however Importantly, I want data to be separated by those columns mentioned in the partition by clause in a question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am getting an error message : ParseException: Encountered: OVER Expected: AND, AS, ASC, BETWEEN, BLOCK_SIZE, COMMENT, COMPRESSION, CROSS, DEFAULT, DESC, etc......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your desired output, seems like you just wanna do this :

```
select
    TOTAL_STOCK_VALUE,
    VALUE_UNRESTRICTED,
    fiscal_year,
    fiscal_period,
    plant,
    storage_location,
    (1 - (VALUE_UNRESTRICTED / TOTAL_STOCK_VALUE)) * 100.0 as New
from
    MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This gives the percentage output however there is huge data in the table and importantly, I want to partition the data based on columns mentioned in my used query.

Comment: @FarhanPanja this is producing what you showed us in desired output ! having huge data has nothing to do with the logic behind it

Comment: @FarhanPanja . . . There is no need for window functions.  I think this answers the question you have asked here.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.

Comment: @eshirvana
It is not possible to show partition by output here. Moreover, I want to use the output in tableau which needs the data to be grouped or partitioned by year, fiscal_period, etc as those are having the same values for different percentage values based on plant and storage_location. Is there any way to do that or is it not possible? Thank you

Comment: @FarhanPanja again , it's not clear what you are trying to say , explain it with sample data and desired output , as Gordon said in a new question

Comment: @eshirvana I am getting an error in this code. UDF ERROR: Cannot divide a decimal by zero. I am executing it in Cloudera Hue- Impala. NOTE: I have 0 or even negative values in the data. Could you help?

Comment: @FarhanPanja if you have 0 in TOTAL_STOCK_VALUE , you will get that error message , so what would be the logic if TOTAL_STOCK_VALUE is  0?